# pending - Waiting for next available executor

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins version 1.537 and I'm having issues running jobs on one of my slave systems.  Even though there are no job in the queue for the system, Jenkins keeps showing 'pending - Waiting for next available executor'.

I searched around online and in other posts within stackoverflow, but the solutions are for older versions of Jenkins, and the resolutions do NOT solve my issues.

Thanks for any help,
Eric

Comment: Have you tried restarting the slave node?

Comment: yeah - I tried restarting the slave, deleting/re-adding the slave.  I'm now trying to re-install the Jenkins master..not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 3):

I increased the **number of available executors to 4 & restarted the instance**. This solved the issue. Also I got faced with memory issue in the /var/lib/jenkins folder which I fixed by deleting the contents in ./m2 repository which amounted to free space

Comment: It seems there are concurrent processes within the same pipeline that need to run and can get in a deadlock state. Increasing the number of available executors allowed the pipeline to proceed for larger projects which require a larger number of stages.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by re-installing and copying my job folders to the new install.  I  tried a bunch of other things that did not help.